# Lapack with Cygwin 64bit and C++ code

Tags: c++, cygwin, static-linking, lapack

I'd like to learn how to use lapack together with C/C++ code in Windows. I am a C/C++ programming newbie, so I know how to code in C, how to organize the code in h/c files, and how to compile them with gcc under cygwin / MinWG / VS. What I'm totally new to is the use of external libraries, such as lapack.

To learn how to use it with Cygwin (64bit), I followed the procedure indicated here

(http://matrixprogramming.rudnyi.ru/2011/04/using-lapack-from-c/)

which seemed to be successful and created the built version of lapack in the folder $HOME\lapack-3.3.0

Now I want to re-run this example: [main.cc](http://matrixprogramming.rudnyi.ru/files/code/LinearSolve/LAPACK/main.cc)

What I did was to try to compile it by calling

```
    $ g++ -O3 main.cc -L$HOME/lapack-3.3.0 -llapack -lblas -lgfortran -I ./include -o main
```

and what I get is

```
    main.cc: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
    main.cc:39:23: error: ‘dgetf2’ was not declared in this scope
    info = dgetf2(A, ipvt);
                   ^
    main.cc:45:23: error: ‘dgetrf’ was not declared in this scope
    info = dgetrf(A, ipvt);
                   ^
    main.cc:55:26: error: ‘dgetrs’ was not declared in this scope
    info = dgetrs(A, B, ipvt);
                      ^
```

where the "include" folder only contains the 
           Matrix.h
matrix class required in main.cc

To me it seems that some header files are missing. What I do not understand is how this is possible if the building process of the libraries was successful. Do I have to give further "-I options"? I looked for "dgetf2", "dgetrf" and "dgetrs" in the lapack-3.3.0 folder, so I found the object files in $HOME\lapack-3.3.0\SRC but if I include them as well as

```
  $ g++ -O3 main.cc -L$HOME/lapack-3.3.0 -llapack -lblas -lgfortran -I ./include -I $HOME/lapack-3.3.0/SRC -o main
```

I get exactly the same error which makes somehow sense as they are object files and not header files. What am I doing wrong? How does one manage declarations of functions implemented in external libraries?

Thanks!

Comment: I figured it out alone. For those who are interested. The function prototyping was missing. Adding it as header file did the trick.